# the new visual studio 2013 for web doesn't recognize IIS & ASP.NET

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have Win 7 and I've been using vs 2012 for the past year. I have now the desktop and web new versions of vs 2013 preview.

The desktop one works just fine - but when I'm trying to create any sort of ASP.NET project it just doesn't recognize ASP.NET and IIS installed on my computer.

How can I make it recognize them without re-installing everything?

[image]

Comment: It's not recommended to install on a production PC.

Comment: are you running VS as administrator?

Comment: Are you getting an error? what exactly is happening when you create a web project?

Comment: Sounds like aspnet_regiis?

Comment: I'm running it as admin, yes. and what happens is (photo): http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/1464/z2m.png

Comment: VS2013prev will install IIS express 8.0. It looks like that's where it has failed. Enabling IIS is not required to install IIS express. Since you have VS2012, you probably already have IISExpress 8.0. One thing you could try is to run the IISexpress installer manually from `packages\IISExpress` folder from preview ISO disk. It may give you some more clue.